# Iterate over collection two at a time in Swift

Tags: swift

Say I have an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. How can I iterate two at a time?

```
Iteration 1: (1, 2)
Iteration 2: (3, 4)
Iteration 3: (5, nil)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a progression loop called stride(to:, by:) to iterate over your elements every n elements:

```
let array = Array(1...5)

let pairs = stride(from: 0, to: array.endIndex, by: 2).map {
    (array[$0], $0 < array.index(before: array.endIndex) ? array[$0.advanced(by: 1)] : nil)
}   // [(.0 1, {some 2}), (.0 3, {some 4}), (.0 5, nil)]

print(pairs)  // "[(1, Optional(2)), (3, Optional(4)), (5, nil)]\n"
```

To iterate your collection subsequences instead of tuples:

```
extension Collection {
    func unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < self.endIndex else { return nil }
            let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { start = end }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = Array(1...5)
for subsequence in array.unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo: 2) {
    print(subsequence)  // [1, 2] [3, 4] [5]
}
```

---

This would work on any kind of collection:

```
let string = "12345"
for substring in string.unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo: 2) {
    print(substring)  // "12" "34" "5"
}
```

Comment: Note: the first element of the tuple doesn't need to be an optional considering the fact that the input array has only integers (Int) and therefore it will never be nil so you can declare it as [(Int,Int?)]

Comment: Cool! How about for something that is not indexable by integer?

Comment: @fumoboy007 I didn't know you can have an array that is not indexable by integer

Comment: Actually nvm. Anything worth iterating two at a time will have an index that is `Strideable`.

Comment: Why to use "advanced(by:)" method if we're not dealing with generics?

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski  it doesn’t make any difference if dealing with genetics or not. Just personal preference (syntax). Just change it to +1 if that bothers you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sequence()` and the iterator's `next()` method to iterate
over pairs of consecutive elements. This works for arbitrary sequences,
not only arrays:

```
let a = "ABCDE"

for pair in sequence(state: a.makeIterator(), next: { it in
    it.next().map { ($0, it.next()) }
}) {
    print(pair)
}
```

Output:

```
("A", Optional("B"))
("C", Optional("D"))
("E", nil)
```

The “outer” `it.next()` yields the elements at even positions, or `nil`
(in which case `it.next().map { }` evaluates to `nil` as well, and the
sequence terminates). The “inner” `it.next()` yields the elements
at odd positions or `nil`.

As an extension method for arbitrary sequences:

```
extension Sequence {
    func pairs() -> AnyIterator<(Element, Element?)> {
        return AnyIterator(sequence(state: makeIterator(), next: { it in
            it.next().map { ($0, it.next()) }
        }))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let seq = (1...).prefix(5)
for pair in seq.pairs() { print(pair) }
```

Note that the pairs are generated *lazily,* no intermediate array
is created. *If* you want an array with all pairs then

```
let pairs = Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].pairs())
print(pairs) // [(1, Optional(2)), (3, Optional(4)), (5, nil)]
```

does the job.

Comment: Surely the real goal is to implement ruby's `each_slice`, where we are not limited to pairs but can chunk a sequence into subsequences of any given length (triples etc.).

Comment: @matt: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/27984914/1187415 ? – I posted this answer because here the request was to fill “incomplete” chunks with nil instead of truncating, but yes, it is very similar.

Comment: Great, I was hoping you'd have something like this!

Comment: Very clean! One question: Don’t you need to use optional chaining in `it.next().map { }` since `it.next()` returns an optional?

Comment: @fumoboy007 No, this is [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map)

Answer (score 6):

This is not identically what was asked, but I use an extension on Sequence that generates an array of arrays chunking the original sequence by any desired size:

```
extension Sequence {
    func clump(by clumpsize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let slices : [[Element]] = self.reduce(into:[]) {
            memo, cur in
            if memo.count == 0 {
                return memo.append([cur])
            }
            if memo.last!.count < clumpsize {
                memo.append(memo.removeLast() + [cur])
            } else {
                memo.append([cur])
            }
        }
        return slices
    }
}
```

So `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].clump(by:2)` yields `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]` and now you can iterate through that if you like.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Extension to split the array.

```
extension Array {
   func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
      return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
      Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)]) }
   }
}

let result = [1...10].chunked(into: 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

If the array would have an even number of elements, you would be able to write something like this:

```
for i in 0..<arr.count/2 {
    print(arr[2*i...2*i+1])
}
```

However that's not always the case. Moreover, `nil` is not always compatible with the type of elements in array, like the one in your example (`nil` is not compatible with `Int`, only with `Int?`).

Another solution would be to extend `Array` and add a `pair()` method, which returns a tuple (tuples can be heterogenous). You can use `pair` to walk within all pairs in the array, or, you can extend even more the `Array` struct and add `pairs()` that return an array of tuples. Note that since the second element in the tuple is an `Optional` you'll need to unwrap it before use.

```
extension Array {
    func pair(at i: Index) -> (Element, Element?) {
        return (self[i], i < self.count - 1 ? self[i+1] : nil)
    }

    func pairs() -> [(Element, Element?)] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        var result = [(Element, Element?)]()
        for i in 0...arr.count/2 {
            result.append(self.pair(at: 2*i))
        }
        return result
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in 0...arr.count/2 {
    print(arr.pair(at: 2*i))
}

for pair in arr.pairs() {
    print(pair)
}
```

**Update** Both above solutions can be simplified by using `map` instead of manually looping:

```
let pairs = (0..<arr.count/2).map { (arr[$0*2], arr[$0*2+1]) }
print(pairs) // prints [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

or, for the `Array` extension:

```
extension Array {
    func pair(at i: Index) -> (Element, Element?) {
        return (self[i], i < self.count - 1 ? self[i+1] : nil)
    }

    func pairs() -> [(Element, Element?)] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        return (0..<(arr.count/2 + arr.count%2)).map { pair(at: $0*2) }
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(arr.pairs()) // [(1, Optional(2)), (3, Optional(4)), (5, nil)]
```

You can extend `Collection` instead, to have this `pair` functionality available for all collections:

```
extension Collection {
    func pairs() -> [(Element, Element?)] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        return (0..<count/2+count%2).map {
            let i1 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: $0*2)
            let i2 = index(after: i1)
            return (self[i1], i2 < endIndex ? self[i2] : nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `let i2 = index(after: i1)`?

Comment: Yeah, that would be simpler, @LeoDabus

Answer (score 4):

I personally dislike looping through half the list (mainly because of dividing), so here is how I like to do it:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var i = 0;

while i < array.count {
    var a = array[i];
    var b : Int? = nil;
    if i + 1 < array.count {
        b = array[i+1];
    }
    print("(\(a), \(b))");

    i += 2;
}
```

You loop through the array by incrementing by 2.

If you want to have nil in the element, you need to use optionals.

Comment: You should've declare a as a let, as its value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with one `reduce` and a few `guard`s

```
extension Array {
  var touplesOfTwo: [(Element,Element?)] {
    self.reduce(into: [(Element,Element?)]()) {
      guard let last = $0.last else { $0.append( ($1,nil) ); return }
      let lastIndex = $0.count - 1
      guard let _ = last.1 else { $0[lastIndex].1 = $1; return }
      $0.append( ($1,nil) )
    }
  }
}
let list = [1,4,3,7,2,9,6,5]
let queues = list.map { $0 }
let touplesList = queues.touplesOfTwo
print("\(touplesList)")
// [(1, Optional(4)), (3, Optional(7)), (2, Optional(9)), (6, Optional(5))]
```

Comment: `let queues = list.map { $0 }` is pointless

Comment: Btw Swift is a type inferred language `reduce(into: []) `

Comment: And no need to use two guard statements. `guard let last = $0.last, last.1 == nil else {` `$0.append(($1,nil))` `return` `}` `$0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)].1 = $1`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to encapsulate the array in a class.  The return values for getting pairs of items would be optionals to protect against out-of-range calls.

Example:

```
class Pairs {

    let source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  // Or set with init()
    var offset = 0

    func nextpair() -> (Int?, Int?) {
        var first: Int? = nil
        var second: Int? = nil
        if offset < source.count {
            first = source[offset]
            offset++
        }
        if offset < source.count {
            second = source[offset]
            offset++
        }
        return (first, second)
    }

}
```