# Reduce swift array to another one of pairs

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming

I have an array of `Int`'s. I need to change it in some way to get the new array of pairs of `Int` (array of tuples).

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// How to get array b which is
let b: [(Int, Int?)] // And it should be [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, nil)]
```

The obvious solution is to use cycles. However I'm wondering whether it is more declarative way. Something like `map` which takes two arguments

```
// Something like this
let b = a.tupleMap { ($0, $1) }
```

**UPDATE:**
There is an awesome [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851288/4315868) in related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550630/iterate-over-collection-two-at-a-time-in-swift).

Based on it I've added my own `reduce` method:

```
extension Collection {
    func reduceByPairs<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element, Element?) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result {
        return try sequence(state: makeIterator()) { it in
                it.next().map { ($0, it.next()) }
            }
            .reduce(initialResult) {
                try nextPartialResult($0, $1.0, $1.1)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate. I have moved my suggestion to the other Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let pairedArray = array
    .enumerated()
    .map { return ($0.element, array.count > $0.offset + 1 ? array[$0.offset + 1] : nil) }
    .enumerated()
    .filter({ $0.offset % 2 == 0 })
    .map { $0.element }

print(pairedArray) // [(1, Optional(2)), (3, Optional(4)), (5, nil)]
```

Obviously the second element of the tuple is an `Optional` because you want to be able to have `nil` when there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
extension Array {
    func tupleMap(_ transform: (Element, Element?) -> (Element, Element?) = { ($0,$1) }) -> [(Element, Element?)] {
        guard count > 0
            else { return [] }

        var result = [(Element, Element?)]()

        var value1 = self[0]
        var value2 : Element? = nil

        for i in 0..<count {
            if i % 2 == 0 {
                value1 = self[i]
            }
            else {
                value2 = self[i]
                result.append(transform(value1, value2))
            }
        }

        if count % 2 == 1 {
            result.append(transform(value1, nil))
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
let b = a.tupleMap { ($0, $1) }
```

Or even that way:

```
let b = a.tupleMap()
```

**EDIT** :

Or as proposed by Leo here: [Iterate over collection two at a time in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550630/iterate-over-collection-two-at-a-time-in-swift)

Here is a much shorter version:

```
extension Array {
    func tupleMap(_ transform: (Element, Element?) -> (Element, Element?) = { ($0,$1) }) -> [(Element, Element?)] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 2).map {
            transform(self[$0], $0 < count-1 ? self[$0.advanced(by: 1)] : nil)
        }
    }
}
```