# Sort complex array in swift

Tags: swift

I have a array like this:

```
 array = [[[2,2],[8,8]],[[4,4],[1,1]]]
```

I want to sort that array like this:

```
sortedArray = [[[1,1],[2,2]],[[4,4],[8,8]]]
```

Can anyone provide some kind of hint or solution for how to sort this array.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all elements in the sub-arrays equal? Are all powers of 2? Are they sorted? Do the sub-arrays have the same length?

Comment: What if the array is `[[[1,1],[9,9]],[4,4],[5,5]]]` ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each nested array contains pair of equaled elements?

Comment: You have like three-level nested arrays for what exactly? Could you enlighten a little more your problem?

Comment: You're going to have to move values out of these arrays into other array to... since 2 and 8 are within 1 array and 4 and 1 are in a different one so a sort based on the actual array is just going to throw back exactly what you already have as. As I suspect others will soon suggest, is there a reason for this amount of nesting, what are you actually trying to solve/store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this array:

```
let array = [[[2,2],[8,8]],[[4,4],[1,1]]]
```

Flatten it, and sort it by the first element of each sub array:

```
let flat = array.flatMap { $0 }
    .sorted { $0.first ?? 0 < $1.first ?? 0 }
```

Now we'll need to group each element in an even index with the following element:

```
let start = flat.startIndex
let end = flat.endIndex
let even = stride(from: start, to: end, by: 2).map { flat[$0] }
let odd = stride(from: flat.index(start, offsetBy: 1), to: end, by: 2).map { flat[$0] }
let zipped = zip(even, odd)
let newArray = zipped.map { [$0.0, $0.1]}
```

And now you can use the result:

```
print(newArray) //[[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[4, 4], [8, 8]]]
```

---

A more efficient way of creating pairs from elements at even and odd indices is to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856224/2907715) beautiful extension by [**matt**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt):

```
extension Sequence {
    func clump(by clumpsize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let slices : [[Element]] = self.reduce(into:[]) {
            memo, cur in
            if memo.count == 0 {
                return memo.append([cur])
            }
            if memo.last!.count < clumpsize {
                memo.append(memo.removeLast() + [cur])
            } else {
                memo.append([cur])
            }
        }
        return slices
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
let array = [[[2,2],[8,8]],[[4,4],[1,1]]]
let flat = array.flatMap { $0 }
    .sorted { $0.first ?? 0 < $1.first ?? 0 }
let newArray = flat.clump(by: 2)
print(newArray) //[[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[4, 4], [8, 8]]]
```