# How to calculate distance from point 2 to point 3 and 3 to 4 so on using ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am making an app to calculate the distance and area now the problem is I made an array and I am appending my nodes in there.

```
func calculate () {
    let start = dotNodes[0]
    let end = dotNodes[1]

    let a = end.position.x - start.position.x
    let b = end.position.y - start.position.y
    let c = end.position.z - start.position.z

    let distance =  sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2) + pow(c, 2))

    updateText(text:"\(abs( distance))", atPosition: (end.position))
}
```

Now the start point is 0 index and end is index 1 but these are only two points. How can I make it to calculate distance from 2 to 3 and 3to 4 so on, and at the end when the last point is touching the point 1 it should give me area?

Comment: Does the last element of `dotNodes` have the same coordinates as `dotNodes[0]`? Or should it just be assumed that the polygon should be closed at `dotNodes[0]`?

Comment: the polygon should be closed at index 0 because having same coordinates could be an issue what do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Maxim has said you can begin by simplifying your calculations ^______^.

I will attempt to answer your question however, using the GLK Math Helper Methods which if your'e interested you can read more about here: [GLK Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit).

In essence what you need to do is iterate through your array of positions, and calculate the distance between these in segments of 2. When your last iteration has only one element, then you would calculate the position between this and the first one.

Since I am not great a Maths, I did a quick search on StackOverflow to find a solution, and made use of the answer provided by @Gasim in the post [Iterate Over Collections Two At A Time In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550630/iterate-over-collection-two-at-a-time-in-swift).

Since my attempt is quite lengthy, instead of going through each part step, by step, I have provided answer which is fully commented, and hope will point you in the right direction.

As always if someone else can help refactor and or improve the code, please feel free:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Measuring Example
//
//  Created By Josh Robbins (∩｀-´)⊃━☆ﾟ.*･｡ﾟ* on 27/04/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 BlackMirrorz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!
  var augmentedRealityConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
  var augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()

  var markerNodes = [SCNNode]()
  typealias NodeNameData = (name: String, node: SCNNode)
  typealias DistanceData = (distance: Float, positionA: GLKVector3, positionB: GLKVector3)

  //---------------------
  //MARK:- Initialization
  //---------------------

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupARSession()

  }

  /// Sets Up Our ARSession
  func setupARSession(){

    augmentedRealityView.session = augmentedRealitySession
    augmentedRealitySession.run(augmentedRealityConfiguration, options: [.removeExistingAnchors, .resetTracking])

  }

  /// Creates A Node To Mark The Touch Position In The Scene
  ///
  /// - Returns: SCNNode
  func markerNode() -> SCNNode{

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.01))
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    return node

  }

  //------------------------
  //MARK:- Marker Placemenet
  //------------------------

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Get The Users Current Touch Point & Check We Have A Valid HitTest Result
    guard let touchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView),
          let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(touchPoint, types: .featurePoint).first
    else { return }

    //2. Get The World Transorm & Create An SCNNode At The Converted Touch Position
    let transform = hitTest.worldTransform
    let node = markerNode()
    node.position = SCNVector3(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z)
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

    //3. Add The Node To Our Markers Array So We Can Calculate The Distance Later
    markerNodes.append(node)

    //4. If We Have 5 Marker Nodes Then Calculate The Distances Between Them & Join Them Together
    if markerNodes.count == 5{
      calculateMarkerNodeDistances()
      markerNodes.removeAll()
    }

  }

  //-------------------
  //MARK:- Calculations
  //-------------------

  /// Enemurates Our Marker Nodes & Creates A Joining Node Between Them
  func calculateMarkerNodeDistances(){

    var index = 0;

    while index < markerNodes.count {

      let nodeA = markerNodes[index];
      var nodeB : SCNNode? = nil;

      if index + 1 < markerNodes.count {
         nodeB = markerNodes[index+1];
      }

      //1. Create A Joining Node Between The Two Nodes And Calculate The Distance
      if let lastNode = nodeB{
        let nodeA = NodeNameData("Node \(index)", nodeA)
        let nodeB = NodeNameData("Node \(index+1)", lastNode)
        self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(joiningNode(between: [nodeA, nodeB]))

      }else{

        //2. Here We Can Assume The We Have Reached The Last Node So We Calculate The Distance Between The 1st & Last Nodes
        guard let initialNode = markerNodes.first, let lastNode = markerNodes.last else { return }
        let nodeA = NodeNameData("Node 0 ", initialNode)
        let nodeB = NodeNameData("Node \(markerNodes.count)", lastNode)
        self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(joiningNode(between: [nodeA, nodeB]))
      }

      //Increment By 1 So We Join The Nodes Together In The Correct Sequence e.g. (1, 2), (3, 4) And Not (1, 2), (3, 4)
      index += 1;
    }

  }


  /// Creates A Joining Node Between Two Names
  ///
  /// - Parameter nodes: [NodeNameData]
  /// - Returns: MeasuringLineNode
  func joiningNode(between nodes: [NodeNameData]) -> MeasuringLineNode{

    let distance = calculateDistanceBetweenNodes([nodes[0], nodes[1]])
    let joiner = MeasuringLineNode(startingVector: distance.positionA, endingVector: distance.positionB)
    return joiner

  }

  /// Calculates The Distance Between Two SCNNodes
  ///
  /// - Parameter nodes: [NodeNameData]
  /// - Returns: DistanceData
  func calculateDistanceBetweenNodes(_ nodes: [NodeNameData]) -> DistanceData{

    //1. Calculate The Distance
    let positionA = GLKVectorThreeFrom(nodes[0].node.position)
    let positionB = GLKVectorThreeFrom(nodes[1].node.position)
    let distance = GLKVector3Distance(positionA, positionB)
    let meters = Measurement(value: Double(distance), unit: UnitLength.meters)
    print("Distance Between Markers [ \(nodes[0].name) & \(nodes[1].name) ]  = \(String(format: "%.2f", meters.value))m")

    //2. Return The Distance A Positions Of The Nodes
    return (distance, positionA, positionB)

  }

  /// Creates A GLKVector3 From An SCNVectore3
  ///
  /// - Parameter vector3: SCNVector3
  /// - Returns: GLKVector3
  func GLKVectorThreeFrom(_ vector3: SCNVector3) -> GLKVector3 { return GLKVector3Make(vector3.x, vector3.y, vector3.z) }

}

//-------------------------
//MARK:- Mesuring Line Node
//-------------------------

class MeasuringLineNode: SCNNode{

  /// Creates A Line Between Two SCNNodes
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - vectorA: GLKVector3
  ///   - vectorB: GLKVector3
  init(startingVector vectorA: GLKVector3, endingVector vectorB: GLKVector3) {

    super.init()

    let height = CGFloat(GLKVector3Distance(vectorA, vectorB))

    self.position = SCNVector3(vectorA.x, vectorA.y, vectorA.z)

    let nodeVectorTwo = SCNNode()
    nodeVectorTwo.position = SCNVector3(vectorB.x, vectorB.y, vectorB.z)

    let nodeZAlign = SCNNode()
    nodeZAlign.eulerAngles.x = Float.pi/2

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.001, height: height, length: 0.001, chamferRadius: 0)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    box.materials = [material]

    let nodeLine = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    nodeLine.position.y = Float(-height/2)
    nodeZAlign.addChildNode(nodeLine)

    self.addChildNode(nodeZAlign)

    self.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: nodeVectorTwo)]
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }

}
```

Based on this simple (and hopefully accurate answer) the result was something like so:

```
Distance Between Markers [ Node 0 & Node 1 ]  = 0.14m
Distance Between Markers [ Node 1 & Node 2 ]  = 0.09m
Distance Between Markers [ Node 2 & Node 3 ]  = 0.09m
Distance Between Markers [ Node 3 & Node 4 ]  = 0.05m
Distance Between Markers [ Node 0  & Node 5 ]  = 0.36m
```

In my example I am calculating the distances of five nodes but you could call this a any point. And of course you will then need to use a formula for calculating the area itself. However this should be more than enough to point you in the right direction.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Can you pls tell me, How to calculate area?

Answer (score 3):

The best performing (and also the easiest) way is to use SIMD -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_vectors

```
let dist = simd_distance(start, end)
```

where vectors should probably be redefined as `simd_float3` (or `SIMD3<Float>`, if you are using Swift 5).

P.S. You need to import `simd` framework first.

Comment: unfortunately i am not using Swift 5

Comment: then use `simd_float3`, the difference is only in types

Comment: ok but the thing is how can i calculate because i dont know how many index the array will pass