# Data to Buffers

Tags: ios, swift

If you had a file stored as data which is much larger than your buffer and you wanted to iterate over this data in pieces of a buffer size, what is a good way to do this? If you could provide some context, that would be great.

I was thinking,

```
let bufferSize: Int = 20000
let myData: Data = Data(..)
var buffer: ??? = ???
var theOffset: ??? = ???

func runWhenReady() {
    buffer = &myData
    let amount = sendingData(&buffer[bufferOffset] maxLength: bufferSize - bufferOffset)
    bufferOffset += amount
}

// pseudocode
// from foundation, but changed a bit (taken from Obj-C foundations just for types)
// writes the bytes from the specified buffer to the stream up to len bytes. Returns the number of bytes actually written.
func sendingData(_ buffer: const uint8_t *, maxLength len: NSUInteger) -> Int {
    ...
}
```

Comment: “iterate but not loop”??????

Comment: valid. Hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: 1. Open file (`FileHandle`) 2. call `read` until end of file is reached 3. close file

Comment: So the question is merely how to iterate one "chunk" at a time? Is this really any different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550630/iterate-over-collection-two-at-a-time-in-swift etc.?

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over Data (something like a big file or photo) and go through it using bites

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *iterate* you need a loop.

This is an example to slice the data in chunks of `bufferSize` with `stride`.

```
let bufferSize = 20000
var buffer = [UInt8]()
let myData = Data(..)
let dataCount = myData.count

for currentIndex in stride(from: 0, to: dataCount, by: bufferSize) {
    let length = min(bufferSize, dataCount - currentIndex) // ensures that the last chunk is the remainder of the data
    let endIndex = myData.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: length)
    buffer = [UInt8](myData[currentIndex..<endIndex])
    // do something with buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file

```
let fileUrl: URL = ...
let fileHandle = try! FileHandle(forReadingFrom: fileUrl)
defer {
   fileHandle.closeFile()
}
```

Create buffer:

```
let bufferSize = 20_000
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
defer {
    buffer.deallocate()
}
```

Read until end of file is reached:

```
while true {
   let bytesRead = read(fileHandle.fileDescriptor, buffer, bufferSize)

   if bytesRead < 0 {
       // handle error
       break
   }

   if bytesRead == 0 {
       // end of file
       break
   }


   // do something with data in buffer
}
```