# Does Swift have one-sided strides?

Tags: swift, range, sequence

I want to do something like this:

```
let sequence1 = stride(from: Int32(2), by: 2)
for (i, address) in zip(sequence1, addresses) {
  sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, i, address.userID)
  sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, i+1, address.deviceID)
}
```

But `stride(from:by:)` doesn't exist.

I know I could just change the first line to:

```
let sequence1 = stride(from: Int32(2), through: Int32.max, by: 2)
```

or to:

```
let sequence1 = sequence(first: Int32(2), next: { $0 + 2 })
```

And I know Swift has one-sided ranges, such as [`PartialRangeFrom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/partialrangefrom), but does Swift have one-sided strides?

Related:

- [Iterate over collection two at a time in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550630/iterate-over-collection-two-at-a-time-in-swift)
- [Swift: What's the best way to pair up elements of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841663/swift-whats-the-best-way-to-pair-up-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: You could also do `for (i, address) in zip(1..., addresses)` and then use `2*i` and `2*i+1`. – And no, I don't think that Swift has one-sided strides.

Comment: `let seq1 = (1...).lazy.map { $0 * 2 }` is another workaround.

Comment: @MartinR never mind I had his last question on my mind `zip(Int32(1)..., addresses)`

Comment: Also in this particular case the number of iterations is known, so `let seq1 = stride(from: 2, to: 2 + 2 * addresses.count, by: 2)` would work as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, @MartinR, for all those other options. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no one-sided strides in Swift.

For a general (lazily evaluated) sequence iterating over every second integer your

```
let sequence1 = sequence(first: Int32(2), next: { $0 + 2 })
```

is a simple, clear, and flexible solution. An alternative is

```
let sequence1 = (Int32(1)...).lazy.map { $0 * 2 }
```

In your particular case I would simply use a one-sided range:

```
for (i, address) in zip(Int32(1)..., addresses) {
    sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 2 * i, address.userID)
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2 * i + 1, address.deviceID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, no. But you don't want that anyway. Too much plussin'. Break up your partial range! ⚒️

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Splits a `Sequence` into equal "chunks".
  /// - Parameter maxArrayCount: The maximum number of elements in a chunk.
  /// - Returns: `Array`s with `maxArrayCount` `counts`,
  ///   until the last chunk, which may be smaller.
  subscript(maxArrayCount maxCount: Int) -> AnySequence<[Element]> {
    .init(
      sequence( state: makeIterator() ) { iterator in
        Optional(
          (0..<maxCount).compactMap { _ in iterator.next() },
          nilWhen: \.isEmpty
        )
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Wraps a value in an optional, based on a condition.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - wrapped: A non-optional value.
  ///   - getIsNil: The condition that will result in `nil`.
  init(
    _ wrapped: Wrapped,
    nilWhen getIsNil: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows {
    self = try getIsNil(wrapped) ? nil : wrapped
  }
}
```

```swift
zip( (2...)[maxArrayCount: 2], addresses ).forEach {
  sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, $0[0], $1.userID)
  sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, $0[1], $1.deviceID)
}
```

Comment: using  `zip((Int32(2)...)[maxArrayCount: 2], addresses).forEach`   https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw7lyza1u7wfqhh/Jessy%20pict%202.png?dl=1

Comment: using `zip((2...)[maxArrayCount: 2], addresses).forEach {` https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezn333byqomjnii/Jessy%20pict%201.jpg?dl=1

Comment: Jessy and @LeoDabus: You are both right: With `func f(_ i32: Int32) { }` the following compiles: `(2...)[maxArrayCount: 2].forEach { f($0[0]) }` because it is a “single-expression closure” where the compiler infers the type automatically. But `(2...)[maxArrayCount: 2].forEach { f($0[0]) ; f($0[1]) }` does not compile. Here you have to use `(Int32(2)...)` or add a type signature to the closure: `(2...)[maxArrayCount: 2].forEach { (i: [Int32]) in f(i[0]) ; f(i[1]) }`