# Remove nth character from string

Tags: string, swift, indexing

I have seen many methods for removing the last character from a string. Is there however a way to remove any old character based on its index?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While string indices aren't random-access and aren't numbers, you can advance them by a number in order to access the nth character:

```
var s = "Hello, I must be going"

s.removeAtIndex(advance(s.startIndex, 5))

println(s) // prints "Hello I must be going"
```

Of course, you should always check the string is at least 5 in length before doing this!

edit: as @MartinR points out, you can use the with-end-index version of advance to avoid the risk of running past the end:

```
let index = advance(s.startIndex, 5, s.endIndex)
if index != s.endIndex { s.removeAtIndex(index) }
```

As ever, optionals are your friend:

```
// find returns index of first match,
// as an optional with nil for no match
if let idx = s.characters.index(of:",") {
    // this will only be executed if non-nil,
    // idx will be the unwrapped result of find
    s.removeAtIndex(idx)
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking the length *in advance*, one can alternatively use `let index = advance(s.startIndex, 5, s.endIndex); if index != s.endIndex { s.removeAtIndex(index) }`.

Comment: Great point. In a way it'd be nice if that returned an optional similarly to `find`, but I guess that would mean it would be less useful in cases where `end` is a legit index you want to include rather than the end-of-index sentinel.

Comment: Yes. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26691258/1187415) is a simple example where the fact is used that this  `advance()` method returns a valid (non-optional) index.

Comment: In theory overloading by return type could allow for both – but because of implicit upgrading of non-optionals, this would be ambiguous: `func advance<T : ForwardIndexType>(start: T, n: T.Distance, end: T) -> T? { let idx = Swift.advance(start, n, end); return idx == end ? nil : idx }`.  You can then use it with `if let` without problems, but have to do `let idx = advance(s.startIndex, 5, s.endIndex) as String.Index` for the non-optional version.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity , how to do it in swift 3.0 ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a safe Swift 4 implementation.

```
var s = "Hello, I must be going"
var n = 5
if let index = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: s.endIndex) {
    s.remove(at: index)
    print(s) // prints "Hello I must be going"
} else {
    print("\(n) is out of range")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.2

```
let str = "hello"
let position = 2
let subStr = str.prefix(upTo: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: position)) + str.suffix(from: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: (position + 1)))
print(subStr)
```

"helo"

Answer (score 0):

`var hello = "hello world!"`

Let's say we want to remove the "w". (It's at the 6th index position.)

First: Create an Index for that position. (I'm making the return type *Index* explicit; it's not required).

`let index:Index = hello.startIndex.advancedBy(6)`

Second: Call *removeAtIndex()* and pass it our just-made index. (Notice it returns the character in question)

`let choppedChar:Character = hello.removeAtIndex(index)`

`print(hello)` // prints *hello orld!*

`print(choppedChar)` // prints *w*