# Getting blocks of 6 elements from an Array - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dollar.swift

This probably has a simple answer but i just cant seem to find it,
Basically i want to be able to split an array up into blocks of six arrays, i can't seem to find any easy way to do it.

I've been using a method from https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar.swift

```
$.partitionAll(arrayToSplit, n:6, step: 6)
```

Which works great, but my app will only be usable on iOS8

Comment: paste code here? what you have done?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: [How to implement Haskell's splitEvery in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691123/how-to-implement-haskells-splitevery-in-swift/26691258#26691258).

Comment: And why can't you use the Swift code from the github project that you linked to? Swift code can run on iOS 7  and iOS 8.

Comment: The code works, but linked binaries don't work, i might try and use it without linking it, if not i'll give that method a crack. Thanks :)

Comment: @bevbomb What version of Dollar.swift are you using? Carthage is supported in version 2.1.1 and it should work.